# What is wrong with my c code (C Beginner)

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x,i,j;
    printf("Enter X");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        for (j=0;j<x;j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
        x=x-1;
    }
}
```

My idea is to print star (*)in the form of

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

but my output is stopped printing only  first three line if my(x=5) why

```
*****
****
***
```

Comment: Why the java and python tags?

Comment: why are you doing `x=x-1;` ?

Comment: so the the star * get reduced each time. ty!

Comment: when `i=2`, the `x = 3`, then `i++,x--`,so only output 3 lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're incrementing i and decrementing x. Thus the loop terminates at three iterations. You probably want a "while (x > 0)" rather than a for with a separate counter.

```
while(x > 0){
    for (j=0;j<x;j++) {
        printf("*");
    }
  printf("\n");   
  x--;
}
```

Comment: The `x=x--` looks a little odd. Seems it ought to be either `x=x-1` or just `x--`.

Comment: Sorry, typo :D, I took out the x=x-1 and did a bad job!

Answer (score 1):

for learning I think it is useful to use more descriptive names for your variables, until you really learn how to `read C`...

```
//not ideal but better to get a correct version fist then optimise if needed
    int numberOfStars = 4;
    for(int counter = numberOfStars ; counter > 0 ; counter--){
        int numberOfStarsThisLine = counter;
        while (numberOfStarsThisLine)
        {
            printf("*");
            numberOfStarsThisLine--;
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are decreasing the size of x, which means the outside loop:

```
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
```

terminates at x/2 items... (because you are also incrementing `i`)

Comment: if i didn't decrease the x, every time "*" is printed 5 times?

Comment: true, but, you then compare `i` to the decreased value of `x`. The first time through the loop, you compare `0 < 5`, which is fine, but the second time through you compare `1 < 4`, and the third time you get `2 < 3` which is OK, but the next loop `3 < 2` fails

Comment: thank you! now i understood. i should have used while loop!!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;x>0;i++,x--){
    for (j=0;j<x;j++){
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @kishan this is what you want

Comment: Thank you !! i don't have enough rep to vote up!! thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    for (j=i;j<x;j++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```